# Can not find license of flapdoodle embedded mongo

Tags: mongodb

We are using flapdoodle embed mongo for writing integration tests to mock the MongoDB database.
Below is the link for the same.
 Visit https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss
This is an open source software, but can anyone tell me where I can find license/EULA for this software?

Answer (score 1):

The license is printed at the top of all source files, e.g:

https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo/blob/b44edf7d4ab02edc4fba22eb75f8f93cb18b4f08/src/main/java/de/flapdoodle/embed/mongo/AbstractMongoProcess.java

It's [Apache 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).